# wkhtmltopdf shows emojis in black

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF files from HTML files. The text in the html file contains emojis, and they are shown in colors in the browser. But the PDF file shows black symbols.

HTML file:
[image]

PDF file:
[image]

I use this style in the html file to show the emojis:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
    body {
        font-family: "Noto Color Emoji", "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji",
            Times, Symbola, Aegyptus, Code2000, Code2001, Code2002, Musica, serif,
            LastResort;
    }
</style>
```

and this command to generate the file:

```
wkhtmltopdf --encoding utf-8 file.html ./page.pdf
```

Comment: The `wkhtmltopdf` project was [archived on GitHub](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) early last year. You may want to look elsewhere for PDF generation.